# How to use ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem with non-static methods?

Tags: c#, multithreading, threadpool

When I try to compile it gives me

> Error  1   An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'ConsoleApplication1.Program.print(string)'   ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\Program.cs  15  47  ConsoleApplication1

So, I marked `print` as `static` and it works. But in a bigger program I have non-static methods. So how do I use `ThreadPool` with those methods?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(o => print("hello"));
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public void print(string s)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(s);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You just need an instance to operate on:

```
var myObject = new WhateverClassItIs();
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkitem(o => myObject.SomeMethod("some input"));
```

Keep in mind that if the type that you use implements `IDisposable` (or some other cleanup mechanism), you should not invoke `Dispose` until you are certain that the asynchronous operation is completed (or at the end of the asynchronous operation itself).

Answer (score 2):

In order to call a non-static, you need an instance. For example, in your program, this would make it work:

```
class Program
{
   static void Main(string[] args)    
   {
       Program p = new Program();
       ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(o => p.print("hello"));
       Console.ReadLine();
   }

   public void print(string s)
   {
      Console.WriteLine(s);    
   }
}
```