# Do I need WaitCallback?

Tags: c#, concurrency, delegates

In the MSDN documentation, I've seen both A and B. Do both somehow both use WaitCallback? Why the different syntax?

A.

```
static void Main()
{

   ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(Foo);
}

static void Foo(Bar bar) 
{
     //do Stuff
}
```

B.

```
static void Main()
{
   Bar bar = new Bar();
   ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallBak(Foo), bar);
}

static void Foo(Bar bar) 
{
     //do Stuff
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current code will not compile. [`WaitCallback` is a delegate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.waitcallback(v=vs.110).aspx) which is defined as `void Foo(object bar)`. You therefore cannot write:

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(Foo), bar);
```

Because `Foo` is defined as `void Foo(Bar bar)`, not `void Foo(object bar)`. Now, assuming we fix the signature of `Foo`, then they are equivalent.

C# provides syntactical sugar which allows you to write lambda expressions and method groups in place of a delegate.

So the following:

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(Foo), bar);
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(Foo, bar);
```

Are equivalent.

Comment: Thanks. Assuming I fix the signature of Foo, can I do away without the lambda expression and stick with the way I passed Foo? I ask because MSDN uses that syntax

Comment: @AfterWorkGuinness Both are identical - so yes, you can do either way :)

Comment: How can you submit a function to the ThreadPool that is not static void ? I've seen this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5786501/how-to-use-threadpool-queueuserworkitem-with-non-static-methods but why does it work if it doesn't match the signature of WaitCalback?